# Where to put Gradle configuration (i.e. credentials) that should not be committed?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to deploy a Gradle-built artifact to a Maven repo, and I need to specify credentials for that. This works fine for now:

```groovy
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://.../nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
                authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't like having to store the credentials in source control. With Maven, I would define a server configuration, and assign credentials in my `~/.m2/settings.xml`. How do I do something similar with Gradle?

Comment: You know that using admin123 as password is bad from a security perspective, right ;)

Comment: Also, posting passwords on stackoverflow would be bad, from a security perspective :-)

Comment: I believe that the above id/pwd is just an example :D

Answer (score 293, accepted):

**~/.gradle/gradle.properties**:

```
mavenUser=admin
mavenPassword=admin123
```

**build.gradle**:

```
...
authentication(userName: mavenUser, password: mavenPassword)
```

Comment: Should `gradle.properties` not be checked in to `VCS`?

Comment: Not the one in the Gradle user home (see path above).

Comment: For some versions of gradles...

Use mavenPass instead of mavenPassword

Comment: I advise pass project properties as follows 
authentication(userName: project.properties.mavenUser, password: project.properties.mavenPassword)
This will not fail a build when no properties mavenUser/Password are specified.

Comment: I had to do the same but to use 2 different environment variables:SONATYPE_NEXUS_USERNAME & SONATYPE_NEXUS_PASSWORD

Comment: is there a way to do this and avoid storing passwords as plain text in environment variable or text files?

Comment: `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` is nice, but what should I do if I work on multiple projects? Why not to keep secret properties in the project folder

Comment: I needed to add the following code to my build.gradle file to include the gradle.properties in the .gradle directory. 

def passwordProperty = new Properties()
def passwordPropertyFile = rootProject.file('.gradle/gradle.properties')
if (passwordPropertyFile.exists()){
    passwordPropertyFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        passwordProperty.load(reader)
    }
}

Comment: gradle credentials management [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:handling_credentials)

Answer (score 150):

First answer is still valid, but the API has changed in the past. Since my edit there wasn't accepted I post it as separate answer.

The method `authentication()` is only used to provide the authentication method (e.g. Basic) but not any credentials.

You also **shouldn't use it** since it's printing the credentials plain on failure!

This his how it should look like in your `build.gradle`

```
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "$mavenUser"
            password "$mavenPassword"
        }
        url 'https://maven.yourcorp.net/'
   }
```

In `gradle.properties` in your userhome dir put:

```
mavenUser=admin
mavenPassword=admin123
```

Also ensure that the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` is set to `~/.gradle` otherwise the properties file there won't be resolved.

See also:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

and

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html (23.6.4.1)

Comment: Could you clarify how this would be used by the OP? i.e. where would it sit in the namespace uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {

Comment: Sorry but I dont get your question

Comment: The OP uses authentication within the namespace uploadArchives > repositories > mavenDeployer > repository > authentication. They would still want to use uploadArchives I assume, so how would the OP's build config look with your solution applied? Do they need to remove authentication, and it will work?

Comment: Actually I cannot tell you since I never used mavenDeployer namespace. Uploadarchives is still a valid task but credentials for that task are configured within maven namespace.

Comment: This answer is incompatible with the question.  It's using the `maven-publish` plugin while the question's using the `maven` plugin.

Comment: does it possible to authorize via ssh?

Comment: for people skimming through the answers to find answer.. create "gradle.properties" file in the project root directory (in the same folder as "build.gradle" file)

Comment: is there a way to change username and password with authenticated token?

Comment: How do i used " username "$mavenUser" for windows like " username "%mavenUser%" ? It's not working...get 403 error...

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea wrt Windows.

Comment: @Nullpointer the `$mavenUser` here refers not to an environment variable, but to a setting in the gradle.properties. So there is no reason to use a different syntax on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @questionaire! As supplementary info, when using the Kotlin DSL, we also have to declare `val mavenUser: String by settings` and `val mavenPassword: String by settings` (if the repository is declared in `settings.gradle.kts` ) or `val mavenUser: String by project` and `val mavenPassword: String by project` (if the repository is declared in `build.gradle.kts` )

Comment: I configured for a private Nexus repo, it did not work under my Windows.

Answer (score 30):

If you have user specific credentials ( i.e each developer might have different username/password ) then I would recommend using the [gradle-properties-plugin](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin).

1. Put defaults in `gradle.properties`
2. Each developer overrides with `gradle-local.properties` ( this should be git ignored ).

This is better than overriding using `$USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` because different projects might have same property names.

Note that the plugin actually adds `gradle-${environment}.properties` where the default for `${environment}` is `local`, and has additional features. Read the link before using it.

Comment: Could you add a full working MWE. How to include the plugin in `build.gradle`. How to use credentials in the `uploadArchives` config?

Comment: @koppor Not sure if this still works but I have used it in my open source project - https://github.com/krishnaraj/oneclipboard/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 23):

You could also supply variables on the command line with `-PmavenUser=user -PmavenPassword=password`.

This might be useful you can't use a gradle.properties file for some reason. E.g. on a build server we're using Gradle with the `-g` option so that each build plan has it's own `GRADLE_HOME`.

Answer (score 13):

You could put the credentials in a properties file and read it using something like this:

```groovy
Properties props = new Properties() 
props.load(new FileInputStream("yourPath/credentials.properties")) 
project.setProperty('props', props)
```

Another approach is to define environment variables at the OS level and read them using:

```groovy
System.getenv()['YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE']
```

Comment: Thanks! However I had to set each parameter with props.getProperty("myParameterName") to make it work :)

Answer (score 7):

For those of you who are building on a MacOS, and don't like leaving your password in clear text on your machine, you can use the keychain tool to store the credentials and then inject it into the build. Credits go to Viktor Eriksson.
https://pilloxa.gitlab.io/posts/safer-passwords-in-gradle/

Answer (score 0):

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: "./build.gradle.local"
... 
authentication(userName: project.ext.mavenUserName, password: project.ext.mavenPassword)
```

**build.gradle.local** (git ignored)

```
project.ext.mavenUserName="admin"
project.ext.mavenPassword="admin123"
```

Answer (score -5):

As per the 7.1.1 gradle document, we have the syntax for setting repositories with credentials as below, the below code snippet should be in build.gradle file of the project

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "http://repo.mycompany.com"
    credentials {
        username "user"
        password "password"
    }
}
```

The above is to showcase the syntax changes in the gradle 7.x.x
This can be altered to make password as a variable as shown in the approved solution above.

Comment: Which file should OP put this code in?

Comment: This snippet goes into build.gradle

Comment: Sorry, I meant original poster, a.k.a. the person who asked the question

Comment: If I could just suggest one thing... if I were you, I'd consider editing the answer instead of replying with a comment. But in any case, thanks for the reaction

Comment: Do you really store your credentials under the source control in your project files?

Comment: The snippet can be altered with approved solution to take password as a variable from local gradle.properties. Main aim of my answer was to highlight the change of syntax in the gradle build file portion of pointing to repository from latest version of gradle