# Uploading to Maven Central with Gradle, Avoiding Unknown Property Error

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to get my first Gradle project uploaded to Maven Central. I've followed [Sonatype's documentation](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html#metadata-definition-and-upload) for this and have created an `uploadArchives` task for generating the metadata.

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

      repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
        authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
      }

      snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
        authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
      }
...etc. etc.
```

The task references two properties, "ossrhUsername" and "ossrhPassword", which I'm supposed to define in `gradle.properties`; however, if I do not have a `gradle.properties` with these properties, the build fails with an error, even for non-`uploadArchives` tasks.

```
$ gradlew test
```

> Could not get unknown property 'ossrhUsername' for object of type
>   org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.

I would like for the build to succeed (apart from the `uploadArchives` task, of course) without having to define these properties in a `gradle.properties` file.

How do I go about doing this?

Would it be simpler to just manage a separate `pom.xml` exclusively for Maven Central uploading?

**EDIT** The identified [potential duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749225/where-to-put-gradle-configuration-i-e-credentials-that-should-not-be-committe) is about where to externalize credentials. My question is how to ensure the Gradle build still executes successfully despite the credentials not being externalized in `gradle.properties`. I would like for others to be able to clone the repo and execute Gradle without having to define OSSRH credential properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to put Gradle configuration (i.e. credentials) that should not be committed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749225/where-to-put-gradle-configuration-i-e-credentials-that-should-not-be-committe)

Comment: Add an onlyIf predicate to your task, and check that the project has these properties before using them. See Project.hasProperty in the DSL documentation

Comment: The `onlyIf` approach won't work, since it only affects the *execution phase*. The mentioned error already occurs in *configuration phase*. Using `findProperty` is the correct way.

Comment: I went forward to use `gradle.properties` with empty values for all required keys. I put my personal keys into `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, which overwrites project's local `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of referencing the property directly, I passed the property name as a String to `findProperty`, which eliminated the error. The [API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#findProperty(java.lang.String)) indicates this method is "Incubating", but it's been around since version 2.13.

```
  repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
    authentication(userName: findProperty('ossrhUsername'), password: findProperty('ossrhPassword'))
  }

  snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
    authentication(userName: findProperty('ossrhUsername'), password: findProperty('ossrhPassword'))
  }
```

Comment: how did you pass the property name?

Answer (score 0):

I just commented the user name password as it was not required and it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the issue in gradle 7

```
repositories {
    maven {
        def snapshotsRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        def releasesRepoUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
        url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        credentials(PasswordCredentials) {
            username = hasProperty('ossrhUsername')?ossrhUsername:''
            password = hasProperty('ossrhPassword')?ossrhPassword:''
        }
    }
}
```