# Where to keep maven publish related sections of Gradle build file?

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I do publish an open source library to Maven Central. In order to do that the `gradle.build` file contains variable references to a `gradle.properties` file which contains secret information like usernames and passwords.

Of course the `build.gradle` needs to be published to the public git repository, the `gradle.properties` should not be published, due to containing all the personal information but without the properties file the `build.gradle` is not valid.

How are open source projects handling those sensitive data?

Comment: I think this answer should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751665/6899896  : you should extract all personal information out of the project `gradle.properties` file, and keep these personal data in your User `gradle.properties` ( or inject these credentials as environment variable when executing your build script)

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks for the reference to another answer, but the problem with the most voted-up answer is, that the `gradle.build` as you check it out from the repository will fail due to missing values. I am not sure if this is acceptable.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks a lot for this - works perfectly for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751665/6899896), with the use of `findProperty` method to allow users to build your project without providing the publishing credentials (issue you mentioned in your comment above)

- move credentials outside the project's `gradle.properties` and put them to your local user `/.gradle/gradle.properties` configuration file
- in your publish task definition, use:

  `authentication(userName: findProperty('mavenUser'), password: findProperty('mavenPassword'))`