# Passing authentication credentials into gradle.properties

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to dynamically pass in credentials into gradle.properties through CLI so the gradle-wrapper.properties can read them rather than hardcoding in my own credentials.

Here is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
systemProp.gradle.wrapperUser=${ENV_USERNAME}
systemProp.gradle.wrapperPassword=${ENV_PASSWORD}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, but if I put my own credentials like so:

```
systemProp.gradle.wrapperUser=abc@xyz.com
systemProp.gradle.wrapperPassword=password123
```

It accepts them and I can download the files.

I followed the gradle docs (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#customizing_wrapper), but so far no luck.

Comment: here: [same problem, different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12749225/592355)

Comment: This solution won't solve my problem since I'm trying to authenticate for Artifactory rather than Maven

Answer (score 0):

Please set a proxy on IDE or read the doc [Configuring an HTTP proxy using gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

Comment: Using proxy configurations will not solve my problem since I could not pass credentials dynamically, therefore I would have the same problem (Credentials would still have to be hard coded).

Comment: please test proxy on the android studio