# How to configure JFrog Artifactory credentials in a secure fashion

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

How to secure JFrog artifactory configuration, right now I have this checked in code as part of gradle.properties and I would prefer not to do so, what would be the right way to get this configured

```
artifactory_user=
artifactory_password=
artifactory_url=
```

Comment: Isn't this working for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749225/where-to-put-gradle-configuration-i-e-credentials-that-should-not-be-committe

Comment: Yes it does, I am assuming there isn't a way to hide it from the developer as well since the credentials are wide open within the company

Comment: That gradle.properties is in the user's home directory and should not go into the repository.

Comment: Yes but all developers would know the credentials within the company and I am assuming  you can't make it secure than this. If a developer leaves the company, you should probably change the passwords again

Comment: There is this library https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-credentials-plugin , not sure how much work is it to implement it though.

Comment: Thanks @aksappy for the tip