# Set Gradle build-cache credentials via Teamcity

Tags: gradle, teamcity

We have several Gradle projects which we build via teamcity and we use artifactory as remote build cache server. Currently the user credentials are hard coded in the settings.gradle. But we would like to change this due to security reasons.

Is it possible to set the credentials for the build cache dynamically during the build via teamcity?

Comment: Set them as environment variables in TeamCity, and use them in your build? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways to do that.

### Store the login/password in Teamcity.

Temacity support password, and will make sure they don't show up in logs
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/typed-parameters.html#Adding+Parameter+Specification

### Store password in the Teamcity user

there is a good example here: [Where to put Gradle configuration (i.e. credentials) that should not be committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749225/where-to-put-gradle-configuration-i-e-credentials-that-should-not-be-committe)